# How provide Stretch=Uniform on c#

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have using `<ImageBrush  Stretch="Uniform"/>` on my xaml code

How could I provide something like this code on c# :

```
 ImageBrush logoBrush=new ImageBrush();
 logoBrush.Stretch= Stretch...
```

There is no option for having **Stretch.Uniform**

Comment: Did you import "System.Windows.Media"?

Comment: Is it a joke? `Stretch.Uniform` is a part of `Stretch` enum and can be used programmatically of course.

Comment: @AliAdlavaran `ImageBrush` is placed in `System.Windows.Media` so the namespace is obviously imported.

Comment: @AliAdlavaran I think no

Comment: @AliAdlavaran there is no nameserver like "System.Windows.Media" on my visual(2013), but I can see "System.Windows"

Comment: @AliAdlavaran And when I add "System.Windows.Media", problem solved, thanks . please write this answer , so I can mark

Comment: So go to the reference of `Stretch` enum and make sure it is in "System.Windows.Media" namespace (press F12 on it). Probably there has been defined another class named `Stretch` !

Comment: Both `ImageBrush` and `Stretch` enum placed in the same namespace but you are asking only about `Stretch`.. Seems strange.

Comment: Whenver you dont find specific class in VisualStudio . Try control  and  . hotkey i.e ctrl+ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import :

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

In these situations first make sure the reference of used class is right.

For instance in this case go to the reference of `Stretch` and make sure it is in `System.Windows.Media` namespace (press `F12` on it). Probably there has been defined another class named `Stretch`.